# The GridView fired event RowEditing which wasn't handled when search for specific row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view with 2 columns one for textbox and the other for edit icon. If I click on edit icon, it opened the textbox for editing and the second column will contain update icon and cancel icon. Also there is a search textbox above the gridview to allow the user search for specefic row.

**First scenario:** when i have for example 5 rows and click on edit icon in any row, it will open the edit box and i can edit.

**Second scenario:** when i type text in search field and click on search button it will retrieve the corresponding row and display it in the grid view alone.

**The problem is**  When I click on edit icon for this row (search result), it shows: The GridView fired event RowEditing which wasn't handled

**This is my gridview:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="PSGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="StatusID" DataSourceID="PSSqlDataSource" ShowFooter="True" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" Width="100%" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No protocal status."
  AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed mb-none" AllowSorting="True" OnRowCommand="PSGridView_RowCommand">
  <Columns>
    <%--RP col--%>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Protocol Status" HeaderStyle-CssClass="caption font-green" HeaderStyle-Width="90%">
        <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="PSBind" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Des") %>' Width="100%" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="PSLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Des") %>' Width="100%"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="PS" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
        </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <%--Action col--%>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions" HeaderStyle-CssClass="caption font-green" HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" ToolTip="Edit">
              <i class="fa fa-lg fa-pencil"></i></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server"  CausesValidation="false"  CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" CommandName="DeletePS" OnClientClick="return FinalDeleteConfirm(this, event);" Text="Delete" ToolTip="Delete">--%>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" CommandName="DeletePS" OnClientClick="DeleteConfirm()" Text="Delete" ToolTip="Delete">
                <i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash-o" style="color:red;"></i></asp:LinkButton>
          </ItemTemplate>

          <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="UpdatePS" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" Text="Update" ToolTip="Confirm">
              <i class="fa fa-lg fa-check" style="color:green"></i></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel">
              <i class="fa fa-lg fa-times" style="color:red"></i></asp:LinkButton>
          </EditItemTemplate>

          <FooterTemplate>
            <button id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" type="button" runat="server" onserverclick="btnAdd_Click">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            &nbsp;Add Protocol Status   
            </button>
          </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>

  <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-marwa" />
  <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDE7" />
  <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#FFF9C4" />
  <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDE7" />
  <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#FFF9C4" />
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="PSSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProtocolConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="ProtocolStatus_Select" DeleteCommand="ProtocolStatus_Delete" InsertCommand="ProtocolStatus_Insert" UpdateCommand="ProtocolStatus_Update"
  DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">

  <DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="StatusID" Type="Int32" />
  </DeleteParameters>

  <InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Des" Type="String" />
  </InsertParameters>

  <UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="StatusID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Des" Type="String" />
  </UpdateParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**code behind c#:**

```
protected void PSGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
        var exist = 0;            
        if (e.CommandName == "DeletePS" )
        {
            some code
        }

        else if (e.CommandName == "UpdatePS")
        {
            var exist1 = 0;    
            //When update, check if the new name is already exist in the database
            //*******************************************************************
            var index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            if (index >= 10)
            {
                index = index % 10;
            }

            var pageSize = PSGridView.PageSize;
            GridViewRow row = PSGridView.Rows[index % pageSize];
            TextBox txt = row.FindControl("PSBind") as TextBox;
            string t = txt.Text;
            exist1 = check_exist(t);

            if (exist1 == 1)
            {
              errorboxactions.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block");
              errormsgactions.InnerHtml = "This name already exist ! type another name";
            }
            //if not exist
            //*************
            else
            {
               PSGridView.UpdateRow(index, true);
               PSGridView.DataBind();

               updateboxactions.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block");
               updatemsgactions.InnerHtml = "Protocol Status has been updated successfully";
            }                
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.

Comment: @VDWWD I implement this toturial now and put a search field. it always treats the search result index as 0 so when editing it will open the edit item for index 0 which is the first row of the gridview !!!!

Answer (score 0):

just do one simple thing fire RowEditing event for gridview....
Follow steps

```
select gridview
go to properties
select events and then double click on row editing and then run the page again.
```

Comment: There is no event in the properties of gridview!

Comment: you will find events after click the thunder icon in properties or just add this in your code OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" in gridview and fire this event

Comment: And if you can't do that than remove Edit from your linkbutton command name and use any other name

Comment: if i remove edit and change it name, i got error because the debug try to find the editing text box and not found it / TextBox txt = row.FindControl("PSBind") as TextBox; << This is the edit item